# Preposition “in” meaning “wearing”

Tags: prepositional-phrases

> I’m dressed in a coat in the summer.

Does this sentence mean "I’m in a coat" or is the verb "dressed" modified by "in a coat"? If the former, doesn’t the prepositional phrase "in a coat" modify "I"?

Comment: I don't understand. What do mean by 'action "dressed" is in a coat'? How can an action be dressed?

Comment: @gotube I know it doesn’t make any sense, but the prepositional phrase maybe modifies the verb.

Comment: I hope you don't mind I edited it for clarity so it can be opened again. Feel free to revert any of my changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the phrase "in a coat" is an adverbial phrase of manner, which means it acts like an adverb that answers the question "how" about "dressed". So yes, it does modify "dressed".

However, "dressed" here is not a verb, but an **adjective** modifying the subject "I". In English, "to be dressed" only means to have clothes on, while the verb phrase "getting dressed" only describes the action of putting some clothes on.

Comment: I don't find it helpful to tell people that dressed in to be dressed in an adjective.

Comment: @Lambie In my teaching experience, English students often think that "be dressed" and "get dressed" mean the same thing or are interchangeable because in their L1, Korean, for example, the same verb is used for both meanings. I guessed that this conflation was the source of the misunderstanding, so I addressed it.

Comment: For me, verb patterns like to be dressed, to be taken, to be seen, have to be taught "as a pattern", as do: get rich, get dressed, get sick, etc.